# Add new roles into the role_hierarchy automatically

Tags: symfony

I  made a form for an administrator to add users and give them roles, so I added this line in the RegistrationFormType

```
  //....

       ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'ROLE_ADMIN'      => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
            'ROLE_USER'       => 'ROLE_USER',
            'ROLE_AUTEUR'     => 'ROLE_AUTEUR',
            'ROLE_MODERATEUR' => 'ROLE_MODERATEUR',
                ),
        'required'    => false,
        'empty_value' => 'Choisissez un ou plusieurs roles',
        'empty_data'  => null,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => false,
        ))

//.....
```

The code works and the roles are added in the database.
My question is, if in the future, an administrator wants to add other new roles, so how to can add them into the **role_hierarchy** automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think this make not really sense then when you add a new Role this has no effect if you don't use the role in your application. So you should define the role structure before and make it so granular you need.

But you don't need to define the roles in your FormType. You can implement that the roles are loaded from an database. So you can manage your roles in your database and define the role hierarchy in your configuration file.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database

Here is the section in the documentation to manage roles from the database. I think this could help you.

**Edit:**

I have found something for you

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html

You can define voters in your case you could try a RoleHierarchyVoter or RoleVoter but thats a lot of work to implement it.

Comment: That means I have to forget the role_hierarchy in security.yml and delete it and then using the groups ?